# Wordpress: Add Thumbnail Of Post Image To RSS Feed

Tags: wordpress, rss, thumbnails

We are displaying the latest posts from our Wordpress site in a news box on our home page. Because we want the first image from each post to show in the news box, we are outputting the full post content in the feed. The problem is that since the posts use the full sized image, the feed contains links to these and although they show as thumbnail sized in the news box, each image could be up to 300k in size, which is impacting on the time it takes to load our home page.

Since we only display a snippet of each post in the news box, ideally we would like a feed that just shows the post extract and the first image, but thumbnail sized, not the full sized image.

Our server (IBM iSeries) also runs Wordpress slowly, so anything that we can do to reduce the volume of data and the sizes of images helps to make a difference.

I would prefer not to make complex changes to Wordpress, since although I know PHP, I struggle with changing code in Wordpress.

Is there a plugin or a simple code change that would do this?

Alternatively, I thought to create a PHP script that would run as a Cron job, Curling the output from the Wordpress feed, and building it's own new feed, (a) appending the size attributes for the thumbnail to the full size post image and stripping the extract back to a desired length.  The news box could then use that feed rather than the Wordpress one.

Since we rarely post more than once a day, updating this feed every couple of hours ought to be adequate, or indeed it could check the date/time of the latest post against the time that the feed burner last ran.

Comment: May I recomend a seperate lintel server.  The only place that I would run web server and db on the same box is for testing.  You should however modify the feed so that images link to larger images.

Comment: That could help to eliminate some of the traffic, and a lintel server should be simple enough to install (even though we don't have any Linux experience in-house). I have worked a little with Ubuntu in the past, I assume install/configuration has only improved in the last 10 years.

Comment: Roll your own experience.  Build some confidence by learning a linux desktop.  Make a boot from usb memory stick.  http://puppylinux.org/wikka/BootFlash

Answer (score 1):

Create the thumbnails then encode them in base64 and include in the feed.

Below is a 48px x 48px, 506 byte, thumbnail and after encoding is 714 bytes.

```
<img width="48" height="48" src="data:image/gif;base64,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"/>
```

To create the thumbnails in PHP for your cron job:
Requires PHP GD extension.

```
$newWidth = 48;
$newHeight = 48;
$image = @imagecreatefromgif('/home/user/images/thumb.gif');
$originalWidth  = imagesx($image);
$originalHeight = imagesy($image);
$scale      = min($newWidth/$originalWidth, $newHeight/$originalHeight);
$newWidth  = ceil($scale*$originalWidth);
$newHeight = ceil($scale*$originalHeight);
$newPic = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
$base64 = base64_encode($newPic);
$thumb = "<img  width=\"$newWidth\" height=\"$newHeight\" src=\"data:image/gif;base64,$base64\" alt =\"thumbnail\"/>";
```

Comment: That is a possibility, thanks. Reducing the size of the feed as well as limiting the image size would be a good thing.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this script. Add it into your wordpress child theme `function.php`, and don't forget to add an ALT value. Very important!

```
add_action('rss2_item', function(){
    global $post;
    $output = '';
    $thumbnail_ID = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
    $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumbnail_ID, 'thumbnail');
    $mime = get_post_mime_type($thumbnail_ID);
    $output = '<enclosure url="'.$thumbnail[0].'" type="'.$mime.'"/>';
    echo $output;
});

function featuredtoRSS($content) {
    global $post;
    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ){
        $content = '' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail', array( 'alt' 
        => $post-> post_title,'style' => 'float:left; margin:0 15px 15px 0;' ) ) . 
        '' . $content;
    }
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'featuredtoRSS');
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'featuredtoRSS');
```

You can see the result on [my blog](https://www.eitren.com/blog/feed/).

Comment: Based on the domain/URL of your link(s) being the same as, or containing, your user name, you appear to have linked to your own site. If you do so, you *must disclose that it's your site*. If you don't disclose that it's your own site, it's often considered spam.  See: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212) and [some tips and advice about self-promotion](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). Disclosure doesn't need to be formal, but it does need to be explicit. When it's your own content, it can just be something like "on my site…", "on my blog…", etc.